# Having trouble making tiles swap positions - bejeweled

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm having a problem with arrays in a game I am creating, which is similar to Bejeweled.

In this game, I have one class called Tile, which represents one colored tile on the board, along with its column and row (integers)on the board. I have another class for the board, called Board, that manages these tiles in a 2D array of integers, organized by column and row.

My problem occurs I swap two tiles on the screen. When this happens, their columns and rows are swapped, but the array that they are saved in does not recognize this change. On the screen, everything looks fine. The two tiles will switch positions.

For instance, if I have two adjacent tiles that I want to switch, at `(column0, row0)` and `(column1, row0)`. In my array of tiles, these are tiles `array[0][0]` and `array[1][0]`. When I switch them, the first tile is now at the second tile's old position, and the second tile is now at the first tile's old position. However, the first tile is still recognized as `array[0][0]`, even though it should now be `array[1][0]`.

The significance of this is that my program will not recognize three consecutive tiles with the same color, and therefore it will not clear them from the board.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

If you have any suggestions at all, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code segment that does the swapping? A common mistake with swapping is to do a = b; b = a; but that will really assign both variables to the old value of b. You need a temporary location for saving the old value of a: tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp.

Comment: yes I have placeholders for switching columns and rows. I think that is why it still is painted on the screen correctly. Good idea though

Comment: Do you swap the array elements at all? The array will not notice automatically that you change the coordinates inside Tile... It sounds like you still need to do tmp = array[c0][r0]; array[c0][r0] = array[c1][r1]; array[c1][r1] = tmp

Comment: How do You recognize witch tile is in witch position in array?

Comment: From your question there seems to be a problem with the consistency between the positions in the array (used for checks) and the position stored in the tile (used for drawing). I have posted some example code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is wrong from your description. The code should look similar to this:

```
class Tile {
  int col;
  int row;
  void setPos(int newCol, int newRow) {
    col = newCol;
    row = newRow;
}

class Board {
  Tile[][] array;

  void swap(int col0, int row0, int col1, int row1) {
    // Get hold of the tile objects to swap
    Tile tile0 = array[col0][row0];
    Tile tile1 = array[col1][row1];

    // Swap the positions stored in the tile objects
    tile0.setPos(col1, row1);
    tile1.setPos(col0, row0); 

    // Swap the tile objects in the array
    array[col0][row0] = tile1;
    array[col1][row1] = tile0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I pretty much have this. It is just causing a nullpointerexception error in another method that I have. I'm working on that now. Thank you very much though!